# Help with creating equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanted to know how many times the number $11$ appears at least once in any decimal expansion. For instance some decimal expansions under $10^6$ could be:

$341011$, $511993$, $118$, $1101100$

all of which contain the sequence '$11$' at least once. On paper I figured out a sequence (I think) to find the answer but I cannot find a way to turn it into an equation. Here's the idea:

Given $n$ digits, $P_n$ is how many sequences of '$11$' you can have.

This is what I found on paper:

$$P_1 = 0\\()\\
P_2 = 1\\(11)\\
P_3 = 3\\(11, 110, 111)\\
P_4 = 8\\(11, 110, 111, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111)\\
P_5 = 19\\(...)\\$$

So it seems $P_{n+1} = 2\cdot P_n+(n-1)$

However I don't like that because it means I would have to calculate sequentially up to $p(n)$ to get the next number. I'd like to jam $n$ into the equation and get a number outright.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: how many times does 11 appear in 111? I guess the problem needs clarification. assuming your formula is correct then you can look under "linear recurrence relation" to see how to solve it. It would be something similar to the formula for Fibonacci case.

Comment: Added clarification that I'm looking for any number that contains 11 at least once. So 111 would count as a single hit. Also looking up linear recurrence relation now

Comment: Sorry, But I still cannot understand the statement. For example how does $p(3)=3$?

Comment: If for example you have 3 digits, or $p(3)$ you can have the combinations $011$, $110$, or $111$ where the digit 0 can be any number other than 1 of course for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't $p(3) = 19$? (The set of numbers is 11; 110, 111, ..., 119; and 211, 311, ..., 911.)

Comment: Ya, your right Kyle. I'm scribbling in my notepad right now trying to adapt the equation to fit all possible values now... I found out through Maesumi that what I want to do is linear recurrence simplification... but sofar I can only understand how to simplify a sequence like $$P_{n+1} = 2\cdot P_n$$

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do something that produces an integer sequence, it's a good idea to check it against the OEIS.  In this case $1,3,8,19$ leads to [A008466](http://oeis.org/A008466), which should provide the answer you're looking for, at least for binary expansions.

For decimal expansions, there is a simple recursion for the number of $n$-digit strings (allowing $0$ as the lead digit, as the OP implicitly does) that *don't* contain a $11$:

$$a(n)=9a(n-1)+9a(n-2)$$

This is because an $n$-string without a $11$ either starts with something other than a $1$ and ends with an $(n-1)$-string without a $11$ or else starts with a $1$ followed by a non-$1$, followed by an $(n-2)$-string without a $11$.  With $a(1)=10$ and $a(2)=99$, we get the sequence

$$10,99,981,9720,96309,954261,\ldots$$

The sequence for the number of $n$-digit strings *with* a $11$, therefore, is $10^n-a(n)$, i.e.

$$0,1,19,280,3691,45739,\ldots$$

One can derive a Binet-type formula for the $a(n)$'s showing they grow like powers of $(9+3\sqrt{13})/2\approx9.908$.

Comment: That's a great idea! In fact right before I checked the page for updates I searched for a difference series that I'm trying to solve from the help I got from Kyle. Right now my sequence is 1, 19, 280 which turns up no results that seem relevant...

Answer (score 0):

This is really a problem about [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), which are just ways of expressing a number in a sequence in terms of the previous numbers in the sequence.  For representation in binary, your recurrence $P_{n+1} = 2P_n + (n-1)$ is not quite right; $P_6$ ends up being $43 = 2P_5 + 5$, not $2P_5  + 4$.

Since you seem to actually want to work in base 10, but your example is base 2, let's just make the base $b$ and find an answer in general.  If you want a specific answer, just set $b = 10$ or $b = 2$.

To build a recurrence relation you should think about how to get a new term $P_{n+1}$ in general using old terms.  Well, suppose you have $n+1$ digits with $11$ somewhere in the middle.  What are the possible first digits, including $0$ digits?

- The $n+1$ digits could start out with a digit that isn't $1$.  In this case, there has to be a $11$ somewhere in the remaining digits.  How many ways are there to put a $11$ somewhere in the remaining $n$ digits?  That's just $P_n$!  So there are $b-1$ choices for the first digit, and $P_n$ choices for the rest of them in this case, for $(b-1)P_n$ total sequences possible.
- The $n+1$ digits could start out with a $1$, and then continue with digit that isn't $1$.  Then the $11$ has to be somewhere in the last $n-1$ digits, and the second digit can be any one of $b-1$ non-$1$ digits, so there are $(b-1)P_{n-1}$ sequences possible here.
- Otherwise, the $n+1$ digits start out with $11$.  Then there is already a $11$ in the first two digits, so the last $n-1$ digits can be anything they please.  There are $b^{n-1}$ ways to pick the last $n-1$ digits.

In summary, we have the recurrence relation
$$
P_{n+1} = (b-1)P_n + (b-1)P_{n-1} + b^{n-1} \tag{1}
$$

We can check (just to make sure we didn't mess up the counting) that (1) works in the binary case.  It becomes $P_{n+1} = P_n + P_{n-1} + 2^{n-1}$, and indeed we have:
\begin{align*}
3 &= 0 + 1 + 2^1 \\
8 &= 3 + 1 + 2^2 \\
19 &= 8 + 3 + 2^3 \\
43 &= 19 + 8 + 2^4
\end{align*}

Now we should solve the recurrence.
But first, there's a way to make the recurrence a lot nicer.
If $Q_n = b^n - P_n$ is the number of sequences of $n$ digits which *don't* have a 11, then the recurrence (1) becomes the much nicer
$$
Q_n = (b-1)(Q_{n-1} + Q_{n-2}) \tag{2}
$$
which you can show by either algebraically manipulating (1), or just reasoning directly the same way we discovered (1).

I won't bore you with the details (unless you want them), but using
[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) gives a formula for $Q_n$ depending essentially on the roots of the equation $1 - (b-1)x - (b-1)x^2 = 0$.
In particular, if $1 - (b-1)x - (b-1)x^2 = (1 - rx)(1 - sx)$, then 
$$
Q_n = \frac{1+r}{r-s} r^n + \frac{1+s}{s-r} s^n
$$
Therefore, the formula you want is
$$
P_n = b^n - \frac{1+r}{r-s} r^n - \frac{1+s}{s-r} s^n \tag{3}
$$
where $r$ and $s$ are defined above, and can be solved for using the quadratic formula.
You can also prove directly that the (3) holds by showing that it satisfies $P_1 = 0$, $P_2 = 1$, and the recurrence given in (1) for all $n$.